# Absolute minimum value

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $A(6,3,4)$, $B(4,8,3)$, $P(a,0,0)$, and $Q(0,b,0)$, where $a$, $b\in\mathbb{R}$. Find the absolute minimum value of $\overline{AP}+\overline{PQ}+\overline{QB}$.

Comment: Where are you having trouble? Are you able to fin an equation for the value of AP + PQ + QB in terms of a and b?

Comment: $\overline{AP}+\overline{PQ}+\overline{QB}=\sqrt{(a-6)^{2}+25}+\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}}+\sqrt{(b-8)^{2}+25}$.

Comment: Notice that points $P$ and $Q$ are on the x- and y-axes, respectively.  What would be the _shortest_ distance from either $A$ or $B$ to one of these points? (Remember that you can put $P$ and $Q$ wherever you need to on those axes. How could you make $AP$ and $QB$ as short as possible?)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

you can flip the A to A', B to B'. then the shortest distance become a physics problem.

EDIT: I made a msitake as the heights is different of A and B. let A" and B" are feet of A' and B',so A"B" is not a straight line . According to Force analyze, $ F_{A'}=F_{B'}=F_{P}=F_{Q}, (F_{A_v})^2+ (F_{A_h})^2=(F_{B_v})^2+ (F_{B_h})^2=(F_{P_x})^2+(F_{P_y})^2=(F_{Q_x})^2+(F_{Q_y})^2 \to $
$AP=BQ=PQ,(A'A")^2+(A'P)^2=(B"Q)^2+(B'B")^2=(OP)^2+(OQ)^2, \to $

$4^2+3^2+(6-a)^2=3^2+4^2+(8-b)^2=a^2+b^2 \to a=3, b=5 \to min=3\sqrt{34}$